# Why does AutoCompleteExtender WebService fail to be called when function is Shared?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I had a problem (which is now fixed) but I've no idea why...

I have an Ajax AutoCompleteExtender with a WebService method to populate like

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function populateACE(prefixText As String) As List(Of String)
```

However this didn't work - *I put a breakpoint in, and it didn't even get hit*. However...

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function populateACE(prefixText As String) As List(Of String)
```

..does work (the only difference being not `Shared`).

Fair enough, but why? If you *have* an instance of a class then you can access `Shared` methods of it; if you *don't have* an instance of a class then you can access `Shared` methods of it. So what is going on behind the scenes?

Comment: Is your method in the page or an actual web service (asmx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling a page method then it must be Shared/static.  But when calling methods attached to asmx services, accordining to John Saunders in this question, 
[Why are Static Methods not Usable as Web Service Operations in ASMX Web Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263379/why-are-static-methods-not-usable-as-web-service-operations-in-asmx-web-services), web methods can't be Shared/static by design.

I'd have to guess that both are design limitations in the pipelines that retrieve pages vs. web methods.

To quote the relevant part from John Saunders' answer..

> The answer is: because you can't.
>
> It's not designed that way. The design is that an instance of the web
>   service class will be created, and then an instance method will be
>   called.

..but still worth having a look at the full answer.

Comment: thanks, should have searched for `static` as well as `shared` ! :)