# How to call web method of master page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webmethod

**Jquery/Javascript:** Want to invoke updateNotification() Fuction after notification_count_span fade out and return false. web method is in master page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#notificationLink").click(function () {
            $("#notificationContainer").fadeToggle(300);
            $("#notification_count_span").fadeOut("slow");
            return false;
            // updateNotification()
        });

        //Document Click
        $(document).click(function () {
            $("#notificationContainer").hide();
        });
    });
    function updateNotification() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SiteMaster.master/UpdateNotification",
            data: '{nForId: "' + $("#<%=sessionUnameHf.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                //alert(msg.d)
                //do nothing
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**HTML** Html code in master page.

```
 <asp:Label ID="notification_count_lbl" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></span>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="notificationLink" runat="server">Notifications</asp:LinkButton>
<!--<a href="#" id="notificationLink1" runat="server" onclick="updateNotification()">Notifications</a>-->
<div id="notificationContainer">
<div id="notificationTitle">Notifications</div>
<div id="notificationsBody" class="Repeater">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" onitemcommand="view">        
<ItemTemplate > 
    <p>
<tr>
<td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="trHeader" Text='<%#Eval("NotificationTitle")%>'/></td>
    </tr></p><p><br />
<tr class="trMessage">
<td>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="nDescLbl" runat="server" CommandName="viewCase" Text='<%#Eval("NotificationDescription")%>' CssClass="trMessage"></asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("NotificationID")%>'></asp:Label>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="nIdHf" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("NotificationID")%>'/>
</td>
    </tr></p><p><br />
<tr class="trFooter">
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" CssClass="trFooter" Text='<%#Eval("NotificationDate")%>'/></td>
    </tr></p>
    <br />
    <hr style="color:darkgray;"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
<div id="notificationFooter"><a href="Home.aspx" style="color:#006699;">See All</a></div>
</div>
```

**WebMethod** webmethod in master page.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string UpdateNotification(string nForId)
{
    string returnValue = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = ConnectionManager.GetDatabaseConnection())
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateNotification", connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nForId", nForId);
            returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        returnValue = "error";
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: So what is the issue? You are getting any exception?

Comment: You can't call webmethod from master page.

Comment: how to call update notification() after notification_count_span fade out?

Comment: @MairajAhmad  so i have to create web method in different class? and how to call update notification function?

Comment: Yes you need to write webmethod in aspx page.

Comment: @MairajAhmad can you please tell the code to call updateNotification() inside  $("#notificationLink").click(function ()

Comment: Simply call this function. You have commented that uncomment that before `return false`

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible due to MasterPages being a server side resource that will not be served by IIS, which is being referenced in your `$.ajax` call.

If you require that multiple content pages be able to access a WebMethod, move your code to a **Web Service (ASMX)** instead.

```
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class SiteService: System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static string UpdateNotification(string nForId)
    {
        string returnValue = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = ConnectionManager.GetDatabaseConnection())
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateNotification", connection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nForId", nForId);
                returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            returnValue = "error";
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SiteService.asmx/UpdateNotification",
    ...
```

If the only purpose of `#notificationLink` is to invoke javascript, then you can get rid of the server control.

```
<a id="notificationLink">Notifications</a>
```

```
$("#notificationLink").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#notificationContainer").fadeToggle(300);
    $("#notification_count_span").fadeOut("slow");
    updateNotification();
});
```

*Read more: [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)*

Comment: Instead, we could use Web-API to define the server side method. And can call this method from the client side script. It would be easier but have to make some additional code changes such as setting up of the route in the Global.asax.cs file. Ref is http://www.webdevelopmenthelp.net/2014/05/using-web-api-with-web-forms.html

Comment: I suggest you use your browser console to check for errors and test if the click event is being triggered.

Comment: .fadeToggle() and .fadeOut() is executing.

Comment: You should be seeing either the ajax request/response or at least an error saying that it can't find updateNotification(). I'm not sure what else to suggest. Sorry.

Comment: If this is in an asmx file it should not be static according to the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735178/unknown-web-method-parameter-name-methodname. Couldn't get this to work until I removed the "static".