# asp webservice, not all methods seem to be callable?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services

I figured I'd jump in and create a webservice following an easy tutorial for my first go ahead.

I got the webservice to work, so now I want to add data to my database.  However, when I look at my preview form, I cannot find my `InsertComment` void.[image]

Here is my code

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace MyFirstWebService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Math
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Math : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return (a + b);
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public System.Single Subtract(System.Single A, System.Single B)
        {
            return (A - B);
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public System.Single Multiply(System.Single A, System.Single B)
        {
            return A * B;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public System.Single Divide(System.Single A, System.Single B)
        {
            if (B == 0)
                return -1;
            return Convert.ToSingle(A / B);
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static void InsertComment(string value)
        {
            SqlParameter sqlParameter = new SqlParameter();
            sqlParameter.ParameterName = "NewComment";
            sqlParameter.Value = value;
            List<SqlParameter> sqlParam = new List<SqlParameter>();
            sqlParam.Add(sqlParameter);
            SQLOperations.executeStoredProcedure("InsertNewComment", sqlParam);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on why the InserComment method isn't usable would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: [Why are Static Methods not Usable as Web Service Operations in ASMX Web Services?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263379/why-are-static-methods-not-usable-as-web-service-operations-in-asmx-web-services)

Comment: @ToddB  i accepted mahmoud answer for the question but upvoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is static function. Review this question and answer in the below post

[Why are Static Methods not Usable as Web Service Operations in ASMX Web Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263379/why-are-static-methods-not-usable-as-web-service-operations-in-asmx-web-services)