# AJAX request to asmx-Service gets Error 500 "There was an error processing the request."

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, sharepoint-2010, asmx

I have a problem with the following ajax request, which worked fine bevor, but on another virtual machine. Because of simplicity reasons, I keep the example simple.

This is my asmx-WebService with GetData method:

```
        [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
            [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
            [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
            [ScriptService]
            class CpmService
            {
                [WebMethod]
                [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
                public object GetData(string WebId)
                {  return new{Result = result};   }
            }
```

and the AJAX request:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: serviceURL + "/GetData",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json",
                data:  '{"":""}', //'{"WebId":"'  + curWeb.get_id() +'"}',
                success: doFirst,
                error: doSecond
    });
```

Only the error handler doSecond is executed, but never the  doFirst method. And the error message is:

```
{Message: "There was an error processing the request.", StackTrace: "", ExceptionType: ""}
```

What I tried(without success):

- reformat the data parameter of the AJAX request   '{"":""}',  or {"WebId":"'  + curWeb.get_id() +'"}',  or "", or "{}", etc.
- remove the `UseHttpGet = false` attribute from the web service method GetData
- search for solution in Stackoverflow

Comment: It's been a while , but I think webMethods have to be static

Comment: Thanks Scott, I found this diskussion, according to which Static Methods are not usable in ASMX Web Services. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263379/why-are-static-methods-not-usable-as-web-service-operations-in-asmx-web-services

Comment: @user615993 If you log on to the web server, you should be able to find a corresponding ASP.NET error in the application logs (under Diagnostics in the Server Manager).

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, there aren't error messages, nor in the SharePoint ULS Log Viewer, nor in the Server Manager Event Viewer.